# How to import/export json into cloud firestore using flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having set of data in cloud firestore (Not Realtime database) which I'm using in my Flutter app. I also have additional data in JSON format. I need to convert those JSON data into cloud firestore collections and documents so that I can use the data in my app. My problem is that I'm not using any classes in the cloud firestore(only set of collections and documents).

Screenshot of the firestore db:
[image]

Inside the collection 8.00-10.00AM:
[image]

Comment: How are your collections and documents structured? Which attributes are stored in each document?

Comment: iam having a collection "Patients" and document "User1,user2,etc.." and inside each user i have a set of key value pairs like name,address,image_url,etc...And i have another collection called "Prescriptions" in which i will have set of tablets assigned to each user for particular dates.

Comment: It would really help if you would add a screenshot for each collection. But you can get all the data through a snapshot and a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) where you can handle the return (your collection or documents).

Comment: yes i can able to handle the return(snapshots and streams),But how to upload data as documents and collections onto firestore?@flarkmarup

Comment: i have added the screenshots into the question @flarkmarup

Comment: This [video](https://youtu.be/ipa3T_gVe8U) helper me out. You will have to add multiple cascading `.collection([COLLECTION_NAME])` and `.document([DOCUMENT_NAME])` when you have chosen to nest your data, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore data already has a nested JSON-like structure. To read it in json, you can print the snapshot of your query.

e.g.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    // doc contains a Map and is in json format
  });
});
```

Importing/writing data to Cloud Firestore with JSON is also similar. You can map the JSON data into a Map to be able to write it to Firestore. It's discussed in more detail in this [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#writing-data).